# Como realizar selects através dos Diagramas Workbench?

Tags: sql, mysql

Estou migrando para o Mysql WorkBench e preciso realizar um relacionamento entre tabelas `SELECT... INNER JOIN... LEFT JOIN...`, mas eu queria realizar através do esquema de Diagramas. Como posso proceder neste caso?

Comment: Não tenho na minha máquina, mas clicar e arrastar um campo para outra tabela não cria automaticamente o vinculo?

Comment: Entendo. Mas gostaria de saber onde encontro essa funcionalidade. Lembro que no Access tinha, mas não encontro no WorkBench

Comment: @WebCraft conseguiu resolver seu problema?